# Список всех сообщений выводится нормально, а с полной версии сообщения проблема[закрыт]

Tags: php, mysql

Переписка на сайте с открытой сессией. Значит, есть файл `mes.php` - список всех укороченных сообщений (этот файл работает нормально) и есть файл `full_mes.php` - полная версия сообщения. Т.е. на странице mes.php кликаешь по обрезанному тексту и попадаешь на `full_mes.php где должна показываться полная версия сообщения`.

Проблема вот в чём: чтобы не заморачиваться сменой аккаунтов, я отправляю сообщения самому себе. И последнее сообщение, которое я отправлю -  в полной версии выглядит нормально, а все полученные до этого - отображается последнее отправленное сообщение.

Я знаю где проблема, но не знаю, как её решить. А проблема в файле `full_mes.php`. Вот строчка кода, которая отвечает за извлечение сообщения:

$tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE poluchatel='$login' ORDER BY id DESC",$db); 
$messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp);

Примечание: `$login = $_SESSION['login'];` т.е. логин под который открыта сессия. Поля таблицы `messages`:

1. id (auto_increment)
2. author
3. poluchate
4. text
5. view
6. date

Я понимаю, что в запросе к БД ORDER BY id DESC - лишнее, но без этого на странице выдаёт ошибку. Вообще запрос запрос работает как ему положено работать - сортирует сообщения по id и выводит последнее. вот как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Я открою вам сайт `pastebin.com`. У нас тут не настолько скучная жизнь, чтобы было интересно качать файлы, искать ошибки и писать письма.

Answer (score 3):

Когда просматриваете список - в ссылке на полную версию должен передаваться id сообщения, пример

```
<a href="?view=full&id=<?=$msg->id?>"><?=msg->text?></a>
```

А в запросе его надо использовать

```
$id = (int)@$_GET['id'];
if ($id > 0) {
  $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE poluchatel=\''.$login.'\' AND id='.$id.';');
  if (!!$msg = mysql_fetch_object($msg)) {
    // тут можно работать с объектом $msg
    } else die('Такого сообщения нет'); // подразумевается, что если получатель - не вы, его тоже показывать не надо.
  }
```

Имейте в виду, что в таком виде исходящие он показывать не будет. Если надо, добавьте от исходящих в ссылку `&out=1` и в перед запросом смотрите `$_GET['out']` - если она не пуста, то проверяйте поле отправителя (*`WHERE author=\''.$login.'\' AND id='.$id.';'`*)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но думаю вам будет понятнее что я имею ввиду, если я Вам пришлю два этих файла, упомянутых в моём вопросе, вы посмотрите и скажите точную причину проблемы. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: `(int)@$_GET['id'];` ну и зачем писать такое?\*.\*
`!!$msg` а такое?

@Sh4dow я надеюсь это не ты писал :)

Comment: Эм. `(int)@$_GET['id'];` - это значит заглушить ошибку `Undefined index` и привести к типу int, чтобы если id в запросе вообще нет или оно не цифровое, было 0. Собственно, просто меньше писанины, чем 

    $id = (!empty($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;

`!!$msg` - привычка, наверно. Знаю, что логичнее результат запроса проверять.

Comment: Безусловно это короче, но хотелось бы спросить - стоит ли оно того(про id), вот что сложного было написать

    if( isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']>0 )

да, код подлинее, но ИМХО писать

     $id = (int)@$_GET['id'];
     if ($id > 0)

как-то неправильно, чему ты людей учишь?:)

    !!$msg = mysql_fetch_object($msg)

тоже ИМХО бред, зачем делать !! ? :) Неужели нельзя было просто написать 

     $msg = mysql_fetch_object($msg);
     if($msg) {
           // сообщение есть...
     }
     else {
           // нету
     }

Вообщем я в шоке, честно :)

Comment: Почему неправильно-то?) Неправильно было бы использовать строку из запроса без обработки. Ваш код означает "если исходное не содержит ошибки, выполнить действие", мой - "не глядя на ошибку, привести к int и выполнить действие". Заглушку ошибок тоже знать надо, ибо, например, в работе с сокетами `if (!@fwrite($f, $v)) break;` очень удобная штука.

!! тут было не в тему, согласен. Но `$v` не всегда эквивалентно `!!$v`, если вы об этом.

Если что, я показывал алгоритм, а не мастер-класс "чистый код") Алсо, ошибок в коде нет и непроизводительных операций - тоже ;)

Comment: Это я просто злопамятный ^.^<br>
Помнишь как ты меня за пример вывода в шаблонах пинал?
Вот и мстя :P

Comment: Да как бы я понял, последнее предложение к тому и относилось =)

Answer (score 1):

Код я попробовал, он рабочий. Проверь получаемые параметры, на всякий случай распечатай сам получающийся SQL и после `mysql_query(...);` добавь `var_dump(mysql_error());`.

Comment: Давайте пришлю два этих файла и посмотрите, что к чему. Я попробовал этот код, но выдаёт ошибку...

Comment: @Кирилл Романтик, вам следует расшарить ваши файлы с помощью какого-либо сервиса и добавить ссылку в вопрос. Так все участники смогут ознакомиться с вашей проблемой.

Comment: всмысле расшарить? и всмысле какого-либо сервиса?

Comment: В смысле чтобы можно было как-то увидеть код этих файлов по ссылкам которые вы должны разместить в вопросе

Comment: я могу прислать вам эти два файла. давайте мыло